# ¿Cómo trabajar con "Packages" en Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy tratando de realizar una app en Python para escritorio con GUI, y quiero utilizar MVC (Modelo Vista Controlador). El tema es que no he podido dar con la tecla de cómo trabajar estos en distintas carpetas y tampoco pude lograrlo chequeando páginas random.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No sé si ayuda o confunde pero es algo como muestro en la imagen.

Código

```
from tkinter import *
from Vista.PantallaPrincipal import *

def main():

   root = Tk()
   root.wm_title("Pruebas Iniciales")
   app = PantallaPrincipal(root)
   app.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    main()
```

Hasta aquí bien, el problema es cuando desde **PantallaPrincipal** intento llamar al **controlador**

```
from tkinter import *
from Controlador.EstadoControlador import GestorInisioSesion

class PantallaPrincipal(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master = None):
       pass
```

Es aquí cuando me retorna el siguiente error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\tdomi\Documents\Python\main.py", line 2, in <module>
    from Vista.PantallaPrincipal import *
  File "d:\tdomi\Documents\Python\Vista\PantallaPrincipal.py", line 2, in <module>
    from Controlador.EstadoControlador import GestorInisioSesion
  File "d:\tdomi\Documents\Python\Controlador\EstadoControlador.py", line 1, in <module>
    from Vista.PantallaPrincipal import PantallaPrincipal as PP
ImportError: cannot import name 'PantallaPrincipal' from partially initialized module 'Vista.PantallaPrincipal' (most likely due to a circular import) (d:\tdomi\Documents\Python\Vista\PantallaPrincipal.py)
```

Comment: como estas importando los módulos?

Comment: En la pantalla principal quiero importar el ControladorEstado lo hago de la siguiente manera 

from tkinter import *
from Controlador import EstadoControlador

Comment: añade eso a tu pregunta e indica el error que tienes

Comment: Perfecto, ahi corregi la pregunta para ser mas claro, muchas gracias desde ya por la pasiencia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Aquí una solución

( Esta es una de muchas soluciones )

supongamos que tenemos esta estructura de proyecto.

```
└── mi_proyecto
    ├── app
    │    ├── paquete1
    │    │     ├── archivo1.py
    │    │ 
    │    ├── paquete2
    │          ├── archivo2.py
```

si quisiéramos acceder a un modulo de un paquete hermano lo lógico seria hacer lo siguiente `from paquete1.archivo1 import funcion_random` pero esto a veces generaría un error, y si probáramos otras alternativas también obtendríamos otro tipo de error.

```
from paquete1.archivo1 import funcion_random
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'paquete2'
```

### Solución

#### Paso 1

Para solucionar esto Lo que podríamos hacer es crear un archivo `setup.py` en la raíz del proyecto, el archivo tendrá el siguiente contenido.

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(name='app', version='1.0', packages=find_packages())
```

La estructura del proyecto debería quedar así:

```
└── mi_proyecto
    ├── app
    │    ├── paquete1
    │    │     ├── archivo1.py
    │    │ 
    │    ├── paquete2
    │          ├── archivo2.py
    ├── setup.py
```

#### Paso 2

Crea un entono virtual y actívalo, yo por ejemplo uso [virtualenv](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/#creating-a-virtual-environment)

estructura del proyecto:

```
└── mi_proyecto
    ├── app
    │    ├── paquete1
    │    │     ├── archivo1.py
    │    │ 
    │    ├── paquete2
    │          ├── archivo2.py
    ├── setup.py
    ├── venv
```

#### Paso 3

Instalar el proyecto mediante `pip` y en estado editable, para instalarlo simplemente hacerlo así `pip install -e .`

con `-e` estamos indicando que instalaremos el proyecto `app` en modo editable,
el `.` significa el directorio actual

#### Listo

Para importar módulos de otros paquetes habrá que hacerlo de la manera larga

```
from app.paquete1.archivo1 import funcion_random
```

otras formas de import generaran una excepcion.

[Respuesta Original](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323860/sibling-package-imports)